# Berks install on cookbook cannot find itself

Tags: berkshelf, berksfile

I have started using Berkshelf, it seems to make sense, but I can't wrap my head around how it should work.

First I created a cookbook using `berks cookbook mycookbook`. Then I added a dependency to only find that it cannot find `mycookbook` when I run `berks install`

So it seems that `mycookbook` (which is version 0.1.0) depends on default on `mycookbook` version 0.1.0. Why should `mycookbook` depend on `mycookbook`?

```
Unable to satisfy constraints on package java due to solution constraint (mycookbook = 0.1.0). Solution constraints that may result in a constraint on java: [(mycookbook = 0.1.0) -> (java ~> 1.31.1)]
Demand that cannot be met: (mycookbook = 0.1.0)
Artifacts for which there are conflicting dependencies: java = 1.31.0 -> []Unable to find a solution for demands: mycookbook (0.1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get this message if you create a cookbook that already exists? I'm not sure. But after renaming it the message is gone.